R will return api call to console but not to data frame
I am using the adobeanalyticsr package to pull some data from a project within adobe into R.
I can do a call with 1 dimension and a few metrics that works perfectly and can return thousands of row fine.
When i do this with a few dimenions in the call, the code will run fine if I dont assign the call to a data frame and just to the console. If i try return it to a data frame I get an error. The error says:
Error in write - -------table <<- aw_freeform_table(rsid = "xxxx",  : 
  could not find function "-<-"


I run the following:
ROLN_data_v1 <<-aw_freeform_table(rsid = 'xxxx', company_id = company_id,
+                                        date_range = c("2023-07-08","2023-07-09"),
+                                        top=(500000),
+                                        dimensions = c("daterangeday","evar10"),
+                                        metrics = c("pageviews","visits","visitors","bounces","averagetimespentonsite","bounces"))

and it runs fine.
when i run:
aw_freeform_table(rsid = 'xxxx', company_id = company_id,
                                  date_range = c("2023-07-08","2023-07-10"),
                                  top=(500000),
                                  dimensions = c("daterangeday","evar52","evar10"),
                                  metrics = c("pageviews")) 

the output to the console is fine.
But if i run:
table <- aw_freeform_table(rsid = 'xxxx', company_id = company_id,
                                  date_range = c("2023-07-08","2023-07-10"),
                                  top=(500000),
                                  dimensions = c("daterangeday","evar52","evar10"),
                                  metrics = c("pageviews")) 

I get the following error:
     Requesting data...
     Progress [------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      ------------------------------------------------------------------]   0% in  2mDone!
Returning 2725 x 4 data frame
Error in write - -------table <<- aw_freeform_table(rsid = "xxxx",  : 
  could not find function "-<-"


The code you are showing is not the code you are actually running. According to the error message you are accidentally including some dashes (-------) before the code.

ive removed the rsid for privacy reasons. but the dashes are what outputted in the console im not running anything with a dash in there

its only when i add table <- to the second section i see error

How exactly are you running the code? Are you using RStudio? or VSCode? or the base R GUI? Are you creating a markdown document? Are you using the code editor, or writing the command directly in the console?

R studio, if i run without trying to assign the call to the dataframe called table i get an output to the console of the 2725x4 data frame. If try assign it i get the error in write as noted above

Why use <<- instead of <- on assignment to 'table'? I'm guessing you are on Windows, and the <<- is being translated to "-<-". Encoding? And I'm likely to be presenting something completely off the mark.

hi chriss, was just medling to try sort it out as I have caught a lot of issues with this particular package. Whatever <- i use i get an error
